# How to insert image into the Jetpack compose TextField and make it editable?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield, rich-text-editor

Is it possible to show images in the TextFiled and make them editable so that I can insert or remove images wherever users want?
Just like the picture below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X4Cv.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI2g5.jpg

I found a library that is built for XML that nearly achieved the goal, however, I want to make this feature 100% Compose.
(Here is the URL of the library: https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android)

BTW, the input content type will be an HTML :

```
<article>
  This is an article with 3-pictures 
  \n <image id="1" /> 
  \n <image id="2" /> 
  \n <image id="3" /> 
  \n and 1 locked video 
  \n <video id="100" /> 
</article>
```

The specific images and their insert position will depend on their id and will match the id and position of the HTML content.

How could I achieve this feature by using Jetpack Compose?